# Import error when using kivy

Tags: dll, kivy, importerror

When I installed kivy and the dependencies successfully, I ran the simple code on kivy's homepage, and this error showed up:

```
[INFO              ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\Users\myname\.kivy\logs\kivy_16-06-04_9.txt
[INFO              ] [Kivy        ] v1.9.1
[INFO              ] [Python      ] v3.4.3 (v3.4.3:9b73f1c3e601, Feb 24 2015, 22:43:06) [MSC v.1600 32 bit (Intel)]
[INFO              ] [Factory     ] 179 symbols loaded
[INFO              ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_gif, img_sdl2, img_pil (img_ffpyplayer ignored)
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\Python34\ghhg.py", line 1, in <module>
     from kivy.app import App
   File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 327, in <module>
     from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
   File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\widget.py", line 219, in <module>
     from kivy.graphics import (
   File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\kivy\graphics\__init__.py", line 89, in <module>
     from kivy.graphics.instructions import Callback, Canvas, CanvasBase, \
   File "kivy\graphics\vbo.pxd", line 7, in init kivy.graphics.instructions (kivy\graphics\instructions.c:14640)
     cdef class VBO:
   File "kivy\graphics\compiler.pxd", line 1, in init kivy.graphics.vbo (kivy\graphics\vbo.c:5482)
     cdef class GraphicsCompiler
   File "kivy\graphics\shader.pxd", line 5, in init kivy.graphics.compiler (kivy\graphics\compiler.c:2983)
     cdef class ShaderSource:
   File "kivy\graphics\texture.pxd", line 3, in init kivy.graphics.shader (kivy\graphics\shader.c:11990)
     cdef class Texture:
   File "kivy\graphics\fbo.pxd", line 5, in init kivy.graphics.texture (kivy\graphics\texture.c:31800)
     cdef class Fbo(RenderContext):
   File "kivy\graphics\fbo.pyx", line 84, in init kivy.graphics.fbo (kivy\graphics\fbo.c:7683)
 ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

I replaced the code with this line:

```
from kivy.uix.button import Button
```

And this error popped up:

```
[INFO              ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\Users\myname\.kivy\logs\kivy_16-06-04_12.txt
[INFO              ] [Kivy        ] v1.9.1
[INFO              ] [Python      ] v3.4.3 (v3.4.3:9b73f1c3e601, Feb 24 2015, 22:43:06) [MSC v.1600 32 bit (Intel)]
[INFO              ] [Factory     ] 179 symbols loaded
[INFO              ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_gif, img_sdl2, img_pil (img_ffpyplayer ignored)
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\Python34\ghhg.py", line 1, in <module>
     from kivy.uix.button import Button
   File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\button.py", line 40, in <module>
     from kivy.uix.label import Label
   File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\label.py", line 238, in <module>
     from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
   File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\widget.py", line 219, in <module>
     from kivy.graphics import (
   File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\kivy\graphics\__init__.py", line 89, in <module>
     from kivy.graphics.instructions import Callback, Canvas, CanvasBase, \
   File "kivy\graphics\vbo.pxd", line 7, in init kivy.graphics.instructions (kivy\graphics\instructions.c:14640)
     cdef class VBO:
   File "kivy\graphics\compiler.pxd", line 1, in init kivy.graphics.vbo (kivy\graphics\vbo.c:5482)
     cdef class GraphicsCompiler
   File "kivy\graphics\shader.pxd", line 5, in init kivy.graphics.compiler (kivy\graphics\compiler.c:2983)
     cdef class ShaderSource:
   File "kivy\graphics\texture.pxd", line 3, in init kivy.graphics.shader (kivy\graphics\shader.c:11990)
     cdef class Texture:
   File "kivy\graphics\fbo.pxd", line 5, in init kivy.graphics.texture (kivy\graphics\texture.c:31800)
     cdef class Fbo(RenderContext):
   File "kivy\graphics\fbo.pyx", line 84, in init kivy.graphics.fbo (kivy\graphics\fbo.c:7683)
 ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

Looks like the same error with few different lines, and I have no idea what to do. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Looks like kivy isn't compiled/installed properly. How did you install it?

Comment: @inclement I followed the steps on kivy's website here: https://kivy.org/docs/installation/installation-windows.html#install-win-dist
I also tried reinstalling both kivy and the dependencies. Didn't work.

Comment: To test if it's something wrong with dependencies (which shouldn't) use [KivyInstaller](https://github.com/KeyWeeUsr/KivyInstaller) with non-admin installing, so that it wouldn't mess with your registry and you could throw away the folder without any other changes to your machine. You had to misread something while installing, or probably you left a dependency out. May be even PATH problem. If you are trying to compile, install `mingwpy` (in the docs) and it should run without problems. If you encounter `-mno-cygwin` while compiling, there is a question about fixing the error.